# MongoDB: what’s happend when the mongodb drop indexes

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

MongoDB `create index` be slow in the large data collections,it's easy to understand. But why `drop indexes` operation so fast?  Is there any changes of the data structure after executing `drop indexes` operation?

Answer (score 3):

Creating a new index on a collection is like create an new collection which is arranged as B-Tree so you can do search on the key fields quickly. This will look like copying part of the collection.

So for deleting index, it will like deleting a collection, mongo just remove the index collection, and then it's done.

I am not sure if you know how file system work or not but you can consider this problem in the same way.When you copy file to a disk , it will take time. But if you remove file from a disk, it takes little time because file system just mark it unused, need almost zero time.

Comment: It means if i create more indexes and it will create more `index collections`    into the disk or persisent other ,along with the data increase, insert data will need more relation of more `indexes collection` ,so insert data will be slow?

Comment: Yes, but not remarkable, B-Tree will take n(log(n)) time to find item and also n(log(n)) time to update item, so insert data will be "slow" but you won't feel it unless you write tons of data in a short time. You can also use "background" option when you create index, so you won't need to wait until the index is updated when you insert/update data. And you should know mongodb don't always write data into disk right after it get update, it always write into memory and persistent them when some special event is occured.